# Identificar tipos de coesão

Tags: redundâncias

Boas eu tenho uma dúvida e estava à espera que me ajudassem. 
Ela é quais as características de cada tipo de coesão?

Não consigo distinguir referencial da lexical. Por exemplo qual é tipo de coesão no excerto:

> O João regressou da escola. Ele realizou os trabalhos de casa. O rapaz foi comer depois de estudar.

Comment: Quando tu falas aqui de ***coesão*** queres dizer ***coesão textual***. A *coesão interfrásica* é um tipo de coesão textual, mas duvido que se aplique ao teu exemplo dos *Vieiras*. Tens [aqui uma exposição dos vários tipos de coesão textual](http://www.slideshare.net/mestrefinezas/coeso-textual-27809452?related=2). Duvido que haja truques. O que eu aconselho é que reproduzas o problema do teste na pergunta; digas quais são os tipos de coesão textual que tu achas que se podem aplicar e porquê. E aí já te vamos poder ajudar. E quando tiveres reputação 150 já vais conseguir adicionar tags.

Comment: krystalgamer, eu acho que é capaz de haver aqui uma pergunta interessante, mas na sua forma presente está muito vaga. E como vez, já passou um mês e ninguém tentou responder. Não queres torná-la mais concreta. Vê o meu comentário anterior.

Comment: @Jacinto eu já percebi como funciona. O meu problema era saber as caracteriscas de cada tipo de coesão. No entanto, posso alterar a pergunta de maneira a que seja mais facil responder.

Comment: Faz isso. Porque tal como está, só se alguém escrevesse aqui um tratado completo sobre coesão textual.

Comment: @Jacinto Feito :)

Comment: Fixe. Só mais uma coisa. Não podes incluir o texto completo no «O João... Ele... o rapaz»?

Comment: @Jacinto escrevi como me lembrava, mas era +/- o exercício que tinha feito.

Comment: @krystalgamer, também podes responder à tua própria pergunta, se sabes responder. :)